# Problems creating an HTML page that runs various javascript functions from scripts and an external file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-modules

I'm having issues getting my 2nd HTML page to work (they aren't hosted, I just open the files on my computer).

HTML Page1 includes a webform to pass a value to the 2nd page.
HTML Page2 is supposed to use Function1 to assign that value to variable1, call Function2 with the parameter = variable1 (Function2 is written in a separate .js file saved in the same folder; it runs a stored procedure on my locally hosted SQL server and return the results), and Function3 is supposed to take the results of function2 and display them in the body of a table on that page.

It seems like I'm currently not getting any of the functions on the Page2 to run.  When I tried to debug it, I get this error on Page2:

> Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: formFields is not defined
> at onload (c:\Users\Admin\Documents\TU Grad School\Case Study\HTML work\VerifySearchResults.html:40:29)

Here is Page1:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- VerifyOPEID -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CaseStudy.css"/>
    <title>Search: Verify OPE ID Code Search</title>
    <script>
        function validate(){
            var testOPEID = document.forms["Verify"] ["OPEID"].value;  
            if ((testOPEID.length = 8) && (/^\d+$/.test(testOPEID) = true))
                return true;
            else
                if (testOPEID.length < 8)
                    window.alert("Error: OPE ID code must be 8 digits long.");  
                if (/^\d+$/.test(testOPEID) = false)
                    window.alert("Error: OPE ID code must only contain digits.");  
                return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header><h1>Search: Verify OPE ID Code Search</h1></header>
    <form id="Verify" method="get" action="VerifySearchResults.html">
        <fieldset>
            <h3>Verify OPE ID Code Search:</h3>
            <p>Enter an OPE ID code to return information about that institution and verify your code is correct. </p>
            <p><label>OPE ID Code: <input type="text" id="OPEID" name="OPEID" maxlength="8" required></label></p>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input type="submit" class="bttn s" value="Submit" onclick="return validate();">
                <input type="button" class="bttn c" onclick="window.location.replace('SearchMenu.html')" value="Cancel">
                <input type="reset" class="bttn r" value="Reset Form">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page2:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- VerifyOPEIDResults -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CaseStudy.css"/>
    <title>Search: Verify OPE ID Code Search</title>
    <script type="module" src="runQueryVerify.js"></script>
    <script async type="module">
        import {queryVerify_Results} from './runQueryVerify.js'
        var OPEID = "";
        function formFields() {
            const queryString = window.location.search;
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
            OPEID = urlParams.get("OPEID");            
            document.getElementById("OPEIDcode").innerHTML = "OPE ID Code = " + OPEID;
        }
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            const resultSet = queryVerify_Results(OPEID);
            let jsonResults = JSON.parse(resultSet);
            //Function to create table body from JSON data
            function makeTableBody(data) {     
                data.forEach(item => {
                    const row = table.insertRow();
                    for (const key in item) {
                        const cell = row.insertCell();
                        cell.textContent = item[key];
                    }
                });
              return table;
            }
            //Make the container
            const bodyResults = document.getElementById("body-Results");
            //Make the table body and append it to the container
            const tableBody = makeTableBody(jsonResults);
            bodyResults.appendChild(tableBody);
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="formFields()">
    <header>
        <h1>Search Results: Verify OPE ID Code Search</h1>
        <h3 id="OPEIDcode"></h3>
    </header>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>OPE ID Code</th>
                    <th>Institution Name</th>
                    <th>Location Name</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>ZIP Code</th>
                    <th>Main or Location Status</th>
                    <th>Open Status</th>
                    <th>OPE ID Code Start Date</th>
                    <th>OPE ID Code Stop Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="body-Results">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the .js file that contains Function2 or queryVerify_Results(OPEID) which is supposed to run a SQL Server stored procedure.

```js
// Results for VerifySearch
import { connect, query, close } from 'mssql';

// Configure database connection
const config = {
    user: 'NodeUser',
    password: 'CaseStudy',
    server: 'DESKTOP-K73G8HK',
    database: 'CaseStudy',
    options: {
      encrypt: false // Disable SSL
    }
};
  
// Function to execute usp_report_QueryVerify stored procedure with a result set
export async function queryVerify_Results(OPEID) {
    try {
        // Connect to the database
        await connect(config);

        // Execute the stored procedure
        const result = await query `EXEC usp_report_QueryVerify @OPEID = ${OPEID}`;
        // Access the result set
        const resultSet = result.recordset
        console.log(resultSet); 
        return resultSet;
    } 
    catch (err) {
      console.error('Error executing stored procedure:', err.message);
    } finally {
      // Close the connection
      await close();
    }
};
```

Note. This function itself worked when tested before I changed changed `const sql = require('mssql');` to `import { connect, query, close } from 'mssql';` and exported the function.  I did that after reading about why I was getting the error `require is not defined`.  Now when I test it by itself, I get the following Warning:

```
(node:13532) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
c:\Users\Admin\Documents\TU Grad School\Case Study\HTML work\runQueryVerify.js:2
import { connect, query, close } from 'mssql';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.18.2
```

I'm not familiar with ES6 and modules, but it seemed like that was the answer to fix the `require is not defined` error, however, I saw somewhere that it needs a local server?  If so, can someone help me through that?  Also, is this client-side scripting and not server-side?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There are several problems: 1: you say "I just open the files on my computer". That is usually not the right way to do web development. At the very least you need a localhost server. 2: you are using modules without specifying that you use modules. You can do that with `<script type="module">`. 3. It looks like you are trying to execute server-side code (database access) from a HTML page. This is usually not a good idea, you should run a separate `node.js` server.

Comment: One of the most important things to know when you're doing this kind of development is where the code is executing.  You must ALWAYS be aware of "is this running on the server" or "is this running in the browser"?  If you are viewing these pages with a web browser, then clearly it is client-side scripting in the browser.  However, the fact that your traceback is from node.js suggests you're running part of it on the server.  You need to get this untangled.

Comment: @Kokodoko - 1. I'm a beginner database person who took 2 classes on web dev (basic html and server side programming using node.js but the 2 parts were never combined), so I now know I don't know what I'm doing, that's why I'm asking for help.  2. I did use <script type="module"> on Page2... are there other places that should have that?  3. Are there any "how to" articles or other answers to questions that will walk me through how use a node.js server and then display results in html, because I don't have any background knowledge to know what I need to do.  Thank you.

Comment: I would try to tackle one problem at a time, begin with separating the client side (webpage in html) and the server side (node process). Make sure those projects work by themselves (the node.js side you can test in the terminal by typing `node myfile.js`.). The same for the client side. If you can't figure out modules on the client side create a separate question here on SO. Finally, when both sides are working, you can start with creating the connection between the two :)